# Sistema de banner personalizado

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Fala pessoal, estou precisando criar um sistema de "Banner personalizado". Deixa eu explicar um pouco. Eu preciso criar algo que: Eu envie uma foto, coloque essa foto dentro de uma moldura, e nisso gere outra foto onde eu possa salvar as duas unidas, como se fosse uma montagem mesmo. Só que isso em web. Exemplo: http://www.jordaomorais.com/site/banner.php

Comment: Qual o problema? O que já tentou? Poste o seu código

Comment: Ainda não fiz código, estou tentando pegar a lógica de como fazer esse sisteminha.

Answer (score 0):

Bom com css você pode criar uma classe para imagem que ficar por traz e dentro dela você coloca:

```
.exemploClass{
 z-index: 0;
 background-image:imagem.png;
}
```

e na imagem que vai ficar por cima:

```
.exemploClass2{
 z-index: 1;
 background-image:imagem2.png;
}
```

Mas eu não sei como você pode salavar essa imagem.

Comment: eu pensei isso, só que o tem que salvar.